# Fatalities per billion hours spent snowboarding or skiing?

Tags: statistics, injuries, skiing, snowboarding

Snowboarding and skiing are counted as high risk sports, and for good reason. Whether it's a fall off a hidden chasm/precipice, or being caught in a tree well, or simply a high speed collision with a tree or another skier, there's plenty of reasons to be cautious. Such sports are also incredibly fun, and I for one, would never give up snowboarding unless I was physically unable to continue for whatever reason.

It did get me wondering though, exactly HOW risky are such sports are. Earlier, I asked about the [fatality rate for various forms of transport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/184329/is-there-list-of-the-least-to-most-dangerous-transport-types-sorted-not-by-jour) per unit of time, and it turns out the car for example has a fatality rate of about 125 per billion passenger hours.

Fatalities per billion skiing hours then would be a very interesting metric to compare against the car. Same for snowboarding if possible.

Can we even approach a figure for this?

Comment: (Sorry for the bouncing you around here, I pointed you to Physical Fitness when I should have pointed you to The Great Outdoors)